# Bash script to delete a certain number of files with the same prefix but different suffix based on keeping x number of versions

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I would like help with a bash script to clean up my mysql backup folders.  I have folders (daily, weekly, monthly) that contains mysql backup files in the format of <db_table_name>_bkup_yyyy_mm_dd.sql.gz.  In a bash script I'd like to specify the folder name (ie daily) and how many "versions" to keep (ie 3).  Seeing 4 "abc_bkup*" files the script would delete the oldest one (keeping 3).

I guess this was too broad to get some help.  I finished it but I'm sure it can be improved.  I'll post it here in case anyone else needs it or if someone can make it better (without making it unreadable).

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l
# CEM2 - 2023.01.18 new
# db_backup_cleanup.sh (/home/link/intra/system/db/) 
#
# Purpose:  Deletes extra database table backup files.
#           In order to keep only x number of table backup files
#
# Backup files must be:
#   - in /backup/db/<database_name>/
#   - subfolders of daily / weekly / monthly
#   - file format <table_name>_bkup_yyyy_mm_dd.sql.gz
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------  

do_cleanup()
{
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Reads each file from the path
  # Grabs the file prefix which contains the table name
  # Compares each incoming file until a change in table is found
  # Processes the table:
  #   - Collects all file_date_suffixes in an array
  #   - Calls routine to check how many files there are for this table
  #   - Delete early ones if we have too many.
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------

  myPath="/backup/db/$myDb/$myFreq"
  echo "=========================================="
  echo "== Ready to clean extra bckup files in:"
  echo "  Folder =  $myPath"
  echo "  Keeping $keep number of versions"
  echo " " 
  echo "------------------------------------------"

  #-- Looking for needle _bkup_ in filename.  
  #-- This separates the path/table_name from date_suffix
  #-- ex. /path/mytable_bkup_2023_12_31.sql.gz
  prev_file=""
  files=("$myPath"/*)

  #-- counts files deleted
  cleaned_cntr=0;
  #-- counts files read in 
  cntr=0

  #=== Loop Through the files...
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do

    #--- Increment file counter
    cntr=$(($cntr+1))
    echo "------------------- "
    echo "File Number   : $cntr"
    echo "Backup File   : $file"

    #--- get the file prefix (path and file name)
    #-- backup= path/db_tblname_bkup_yyyy_mm_dd.sql.gz
    #-- prefix= path/db_tblname
    prefix=${file%%$needle*}
    echo "Path and File : $prefix"

    #-- If prefix = whole file name then we didn't find _bkup_
    #--   this is not a backup file so skip it.
    if [ "$prefix" == "$file" ]
    then
      echo "  NOT a backup file.  Not processing."
      continue
    fi


    #-- First time in, prev_file will be empty.
    #-- Set it to first file prefix before comparison is made.
    if [ "$prev_file" = "" ]
    then
      prev_file="$prefix"
    fi

    #-- in what position is the needle.
    mypos=${#prefix}
    #--- Debug only
    # echo "found $needle at $mypos"

    #-- get file date suffix
    #-- Last position of "_bkup_"
    x=$(($mypos+6))
    file_date="${file:$x:10}"
#    echo "the suffix is $file_date"

    #-- Debug Only  
    #    echo "prefix: $prefix and prev_file: $prev_file" 
    if [ "$prefix" != "$prev_file" ] 
    then
      #-- Filename change - check file...
      echo "That's all the files for PREVIOUS table."
      echo "Going to see if we should delete some..."
      do_remove_extras
      #-- prepare for the next filename
  #-- Clear the Main Array for new files
      aryFiles=()
      prev_file="${prefix}"
      aryFiles+=($file_date)
    else
      aryFiles+=($file_date)
    fi
    echo " "

  done

  #-- Process last file which will not be triggered by a
  #--    change in file name.
  echo "Process Final File... "
  do_remove_extras

  echo " "
  echo "======================================================"
  echo "Summary for $myPath"
  echo "======================================================"
  echo "Deleted ${cleaned_cntr} files."
  echo "-----------------------------------"
  echo " "


}

#---------------------------------------
do_remove_extras()
{
  #-- Empty ary that will hold the sorted file date suffixes
  arySorted=()

  #-- How many file date suffixes do we have
  nbrSuffixes=${#aryFiles[@]}
  echo "  There are $nbrSuffixes suffixes for this file  (keeping $keep)."
  #--  echo "Printing Original array"
  #-- for (( i=0; i<$nbrSuffixes; i++ )); do echo "${aryFiles[$i]}" ; done

  #-- Sort the suffixes by date yyyy-mm-dd - earliest firstt
  arySorted=($(echo "${aryFiles[@]}" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort))    
  echo "  Printing Sorted array..."
  echo "    ${arySorted[@]}"

  #-- Delete Extra files
  nbr_to_rm=$(($nbrSuffixes-$keep))
  #   echo "  How many files to remove? $nbr_to_rm"
  if (( $nbr_to_rm > 0 ))
  then
    #-- need to delete some
    echo "  We will delete $nbr_to_rm files..."
    del_cntr=0;
    for (( i=0; i<$nbrSuffixes; i++ )); do 
      suff="${arySorted[$i]}";
      del_fname="${prev_file}$needle${suff}" ;
      if [ $del_cntr -lt $nbr_to_rm ]
      then
        #-- debug  echo "   del_cntr = ${del_cntr} and nbr_to_rm = ${nbr_to_rm}"
        echo "    DELETING filename = ${del_fname}.sql.gz"
        rm -f "${del_fname}.sql.gz"
        (( cleaned_cntr++ ))
        (( del_cntr++ ))
      else
        echo "    Keeping ${del_fname}..."
      fi
    done
  
  fi

  
  
}

#=======================================================================
#  MAIN SCRIPT
#=======================================================================

echo "======================================================"
echo "Starting $(basename $BASH_SOURCE) at `date`"
echo " "

#get general variables
echo "  Getting System variables..."
source "./cemsoft.conf"

#---  Was DB provided
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "No Database Was provided"
    exit;
    #-- set Default?
#  COMP="cscs"
else
    myDb=$1
fi

echo "  Managing DB Backup files at path=<$LOG_PATH>"
echo " "

cleaned_cntr=0;
aryFiles=()
needle="_bkup_"


#---------------------------------------------------
# Call as many times as needed
#---------------------------------------------------

myFreq="daily"
keep=2     
do_cleanup

myFreq="weekly"
do_cleanup

myFreq="monthly"
do_cleanup

echo " "
echo " " 
echo "======================================================"
echo "Finished with Backup Cleanup."
echo "======================================================"
echo " "
```

Comment: Show us what you have searched, then tried and what fails?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
rm $(ls -1tr | tail +4)
```

You don't need to compare files, just list them in reverse chronological order and skip the first three. Any files remaining in that list are ones you want to delete.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, Bill.  I have maybe 100 different filename prefixes in these folders.  So, each "prefix" must be handled separately.  That means I have to iterate a list of filenames and get the prefixes (table names) and then I think your solution would work at that point.